# Automatic Scrolling of Fragment and Activity with Google Admob?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, admob

I am making my first android app and its almost complete. so today i add google admob in it. but now after adding admob i am facing issue with my application.

I, put banner add at top of my android app. now problem is like i am at bottom of my app and banner ad that is on the top of the app is loaded. my app automatically goes on top after the add is loaded.

Another type of same issue...

I am on fragment A. there is one banner add on fragment A. from fragment A i goes on Fragment B. now when i came back to fragment A. i am not come at the position where i left Fragment A.

There is no java code for admob in my whole project.

All these type of issues starting coming after applying admob. if i disable addmob code my app working fine. there is no issue of auto scroll. or when i come back to fragment A from Fragment B i come on the postion where i left the fragment A. after disable the admob.

So i think this issue is because of admob. because i clearly applies the stack maintenance of fragment in my app.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/background"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:overScrollMode="never"
    android:scrollbars="none">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/bannerSlider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:overScrollMode="never"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp" />

        <include
            layout="@layout/header_just_in"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/justInRecyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/featuredDealRecyclerView"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
            android:overScrollMode="never" />

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/BannerAdUnit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
            ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
            android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
            ads:adUnitId="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX">
        </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

        <include
            layout="@layout/header_exiting_offer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp" />

        <include
            layout="@layout/exciting_offer_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp" />


        <include
            android:id="@+id/xyz"
            layout="@layout/header_featured_deal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/featuredDealRecyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/xyz"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
            android:overScrollMode="never" />

        <include
            layout="@layout/header_coupons_deals"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/couponDeals_recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/featuredDealRecyclerView"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:overScrollMode="never" />

        <include
            layout="@layout/header_loot_box_special"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp" />

        <include
            layout="@layout/loot_box_special_1"
            android:id="@+id/lootBoxSpecials"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp" />

        <include
            layout="@layout/loot_box_special_2"
            android:id="@+id/lootBoxSpecials"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp" />

        <include
            layout="@layout/group_deals"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/lootBoxSpecials"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/include_header_earnings"
            layout="@layout/header_earnings"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/earnings_freebiesRecyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/include_header_earnings"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:overScrollMode="never" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/headerPinnedpost"
            layout="@layout/header_blog"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/pinned_post"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/headerPinnedpost"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:overScrollMode="never" />

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/hfAdView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
            ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX">
        </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

I was expecting that my app will not auto scroll to top after the ad load. or when i go to another fragment and come back again to previous fragment i will come back to state where i leave that fragment. all these things working properly if i disable the admob. problem is coming when admob is working.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your LinearLayout

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

Comment: It prevents the child elements from receiving focus